# Computing the number of ways one can choose three non-zero distinct elements from a finite field satisfying a certain condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q}$, where $q=p^{a}$, $p$ is an odd prime. The question is that in how many ways can one choose three numbers $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}$, such that all three are distinct and $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}\lambda_{3}=1$. I tried it in the following way: We can choose $\lambda_{1}$ first in $q-1$ ways. After once we choose $\lambda_{2}\neq \lambda_{1}$, $\lambda_{3}=\lambda_{2}^{-1}\lambda_{1}^{-1}$. But we have to make sure that all are distinct. So, $\lambda_{2}^{-1}\lambda_{1}^{-1}=\lambda_{1} \implies \lambda_{2}=\lambda_{1}^{-2}$. So we have to choose $\lambda_{2}\neq \lambda_{1}^{-2}$.  Now also, $\lambda_{2}^{-1}\lambda_{1}^{-1}=\lambda_{2} \implies \lambda_{1}=\lambda_{2}^{-2}$.

This is where I get stuck at and it is not clear to me how to compute further.

Any kind of help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can compute all the ways without considering "distinct" at first, and the delete what you don't want.

Comment: As Hugo said. This is usual inclusion-exclusion business. There are $(q-1)^2$ solutions when we disregard distinctness. There are $q-1$ solutions such that $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$. Ditto for $\lambda_1=\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_2=\lambda_3$. Subtracting those. But you subtracted the cases with all three equal thrice, so you need to put those back in twice. The number of such cases depends on whether $q-1$ is a multiple of three or not.

Comment: As a "reality check" you can verify that the value you get must be divisible six. This is because any solution belongs to a sextet of all permutations of $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\lambda_3\}$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the order in which the numbers are chosen doesn’t matter. Then do we need to consider all the cases?

Comment: So basically what I am asking is that how many ways one can choose three numbers from $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ such that there product is 1

Comment: If I can get that count, it is enough to subtract $q-1$ From that I suppose

Comment: Ok. So if all permutations of a solution are considered to be the same solution, then you just divide by six in the end. Anyway, the answer is then
$$N=\frac16\left((q-1)(q-4)+2\gcd(3,q-1)\right).$$ You need to work through the inclusion-exclusion business a few times for it to become second nature, so leaving the details to you.